# connect exchange server from another origin c#

Tags: c#, powershell, server, ldap, exchange-server

This is my exchange server connection code from my project. If application server and the exchange in the same origin my code working. But our exchange is a diffrent origin my application server pool in another origin. in this senario my code doesnt work and not giving error. I cannot give the mail boxes informations. Thanks for help.

```
public int GetMailBoxSize(string mail)
        {
            int percent = -1;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["MailSize" + mail] != null)
            {
                percent = (Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Cache["MailSize" + mail]));
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string un = @"foresty\activedirectory.update";
                    System.Security.SecureString pw = new System.Security.SecureString();
                    string password = "passsword";
                    string exchangeServerName = "http://xxx.xxx.xx/powershell";

                    foreach (char ch in password)
                    {
                        pw.AppendChar(ch);
                    }

                    using (PowerShell _powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
                    {

                        var credential = new PSCredential(un, pw);
                        _powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("Credential", credential);
                        _powerShell.AddScript($"$Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri {exchangeServerName} -Credential $Credential -Authentication Kerberos -AllowRedirection");
                        _powerShell.AddScript("Import-PSSession $Session");
                        _powerShell.Invoke();
                        _powerShell.AddScript(@"get-mailbox -identity " + mail + " | Select-Object ProhibitSendReceiveQuota");
                        var results = _powerShell.Invoke();

                        string size = "";
                        string used = "";
                        string size2 = "";
                        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                        {
                            size = (obj.Properties["ProhibitSendReceiveQuota"].Value.ToString());
                        }

                        _powerShell.AddScript(@"Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity " + mail + " | Select-Object Totalitemsize,DatabaseProhibitSendQuota");
                        var results2 = _powerShell.Invoke();

                        _powerShell.AddScript("Remove-PSSession $Session");
                        _powerShell.Invoke();

                        foreach (PSObject obj in results2)
                        {
                            used = (obj.Properties["Totalitemsize"].Value.ToString());
                            size2 = (obj.Properties["DatabaseProhibitSendQuota"].Value.ToString());
                        }

                        if (size != "Unlimited")
                        {
                            if (used.Contains("KB"))
                            {
                                percent = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDouble(used.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))) * 100 / ((Convert.ToDouble(size.Split()[0].Replace('.', ',')) * 1024 * 1024)));
                            }
                            else if (used.Contains("MB"))
                            {
                                percent = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDouble(used.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))) * 100 / ((Convert.ToDouble(size.Split()[0].Replace('.', ',')) * 1024)));
                            }
                            else if (used.Contains("GB"))
                            {
                                percent = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDouble(used.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))) * 100 / (Convert.ToDouble(size.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (used.Contains("KB"))
                            {
                                percent = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDouble(used.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))) * 100 / ((Convert.ToDouble(size2.Split()[0].Replace('.', ',')) * 1024 * 1024)));
                            }
                            else if (used.Contains("MB"))
                            {
                                percent = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDouble(used.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))) * 100 / ((Convert.ToDouble(size2.Split()[0].Replace('.', ',')) * 1024)));
                            }
                            else if (used.Contains("GB"))
                            {
                                percent = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDouble(used.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))) * 100 / (Convert.ToDouble(size2.Split()[0].Replace('.', ','))));
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return percent;
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("MailSize" + mail, percent, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }

            return percent;
        }
```

Comment: When you are inside a corporate network port forwarding is used at the firewall and all email ports are forwarded to the email proxy server and checked against the users credentials.  So you cannot go to any outside email server and you have to use default credentials (not username and password).

Comment: thanks for answer. credidential? var credential = new PSCredential(un, pw); is not?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials?view=net-6.0&force_isolation=true The mailbox comes from the users account on machine.  Make sure the user has an email setup.